# could not find gem 'tzinfo-data (>=0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine. Run bundle install to install missing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails development. Just started learning. I installed ruby on rails on my windows 8.1 pc with below packages kit from website.

I am using windows 8.1

Packages included are
Ruby 2.0.0
Rails 4.1
Bundler
Git
Sqlite
TinyTDS
SQL Server Support
DevKit

but when i try to run the server using command rails s i am getting below error.

could not find gem 'tzinfo-data (>=0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine.
Run bundle install to install missing gems

I tried to use bundle install command , but then i am getting below error

dl is deprecated please use fiddle

Please suggest

Answer (score 4):

After so much research below are the steps you need to perform.
I am new on ruby on rails and faced so many issues during installation i dont want anyone to face this who are beginers to this

First install ssl_certificate into your ssl_certificate directory of railsinstller.

fire the command gem update --system

fire the command bundle install

install node.js os compitable installer

Comment: To install ssl_certificate you can follow [link](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88#manual-solution-to-ssl-issue)

Comment: Yes , this is what i did , also there is a need to install node.js to avoid further errors