# Could not find gem 'tzinfo-data (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rubymine

New to Ruby on Rails I have created a new project using RubyMine

1. Windows 7 machine
2. Ide: RubyMine
3. Ruby Version: 2.1
4. Rails Version: 4.1.8

I got into this issue after building the newly created project.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\RubyMine 7.0.4\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) "C:/Users/UserX/RubymineProjects/SampleWeb/bin/rails" server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:357:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'tzinfo-data (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:164:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:129:in `resolve'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:193:in `resolve'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler.rb:121:in `setup'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
        from C:/Users/UserX/RubymineProjects/ZepMed/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/UserX/RubymineProjects/ZepMed/bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from C:/Users/UserX/RubymineProjects/ZepMed/bin/rails:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from -e:1:in `load'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

**I followed this question [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585373/could-not-find-gem-tzinfo-data-0-x86-mingw32-in-the-gems-available-on-this) by adding the ssl_certificate on the installation directory but still the issue remains the same.**

Answer (score 1):

There was some sort of problem with **TZInfo-data** gem version 1.2015.4 so I downgraded the version of 1.2015.3. Run the application and it started working again.