# rails server / rails s not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, installation

I am using windows.

When I type rails server, it sends me this prompt: [image]

I have already cd'd into the directory of my app and already ran `$ rails new MySite`. `Rails generate model` gives me the same prompt. I searched this problem on google and there was the same question on stacks 3 years ago unresolved, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run `rails new MySite`, but you are in `testRails` directory? Could you cd to correct directory and try again?

Comment: So after I `rails new MySite`, you want me to `cd MySite` then `bundle install` and `rails server`? Or am I suppose to run bundle install and rails server in the directory which i run `rails new`

Comment: Yeah you must be in MySite in order to run rails server, console or anything that's not rails new

Comment: Okay, once I do that, I get this error: Could not find gem 'tzinfo-data <>= 0> x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine. Run `bundle install` to install missing gems. I run `bundle install` and it gives me the same exact error. So i run `bundle install` and it's telling me that I must run `bundle install` when I do.

Comment: I think it's another question and it had an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585373/could-not-find-gem-tzinfo-data-0-x86-mingw32-in-the-gems-available-on-this